# pacemaker.log file is flooding with “Too many open files (24)”

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pacemaker

My system is currently at Centos 8 and my /var/log/pacemaker/pacemaker.log file is flooding with GB of data and most of the error messages shows the below message.
These messages are more than 1000 in numbers and they are filling up like almost 10-15 GB of data in a matter of 10 minutes

```
Oct 13 12:10:46 vm01 pacemaker-attrd     [23173] (qb_ipcs_us_connection_acceptor)   error: Could not accept client connection: Too many open files in system (23)

Oct 13 12:10:46 vm01 pacemaker-attrd     [23173] (qb_ipcs_us_connection_acceptor)   error: Could not accept client connection: Too many open files in system (23)
```

Earlier in my environment I was using Centos 7 and I never saw this log flooding. After upgrading to Centos 8 this issue started

Below is the ulimit output from Centos 8

```
[root@vm01 ~]# ulimit -n
65536
```

Problem is that this issue occurs randomly at a given day and I always have to manually empty the /var/log/pacemaker/pacemaker.log files in order to ensure that system doesn't halt after reaching 100% storage

Output of lsof when this issue occured.

```
 [root@vm01 ~]# lsof | wc -l
    416113
```

I've been told to modify the following lines on /etc/security/limits.conf, which is to change the 65536 to 524288

```
[root@vm01 ~]# cat /etc/security/limits.conf  | grep root
root hard nofile 1048576
root soft nofile 65536
```

One more change is to make the following change on /etc/sysctl.conf , which is to again change 65536 to 524288, followed by runing /sbin/sysctl -p

```
[root@vm01 ~]# cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep -i fs.file
fs.file-max = 65536
```

Kindly assist me on this problem and also let me know if the change for sysctl.conf and limits.conf can be applied on the environment to fix this

Answer (score 0):

What is the ulimit of your `pacemaker`-process?

Find out with `cat /proc/<procid>/limits`

example:

```
$ cat /proc/8933/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             128443               128443               processes
Max open files            16384                16384                files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       128443               128443               signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

This will help you to analyze this further.

If your `pacemaker` is running with a lower ulimit and you're using systemd, you can just add a systemd-drop-in (configuration) to add configuration to your service without manipulating the original unit-file for `pacemaker`.

If your systemd-unit-file has this path:
`/etc/systemd/system/pacemaker.service`, you can create a directory `/etc/systemd/system/pacemaker` and put a file with the extension `.conf.` into this directory.

The content of this file could be:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=65536
```

Do `systemctl daemon-reload` afterwards, restart pacemaker and the changes should get applied.

Reference: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

Comment: Thanks for the response and below is the output 

$ cat /proc/11550/limits | grep open
Max open files            1024                 4096         files  

In our environment, we use /etc/systemd/system/pacemaker.service, so I added LimitNOFILE=65536 directly under [Service] and did a daemon reload and post that it is changed as follows

$ systemctl show pacemaker.service | grep -i nofile
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitNOFILESoft=65536

$ cat /proc/10336/limits | grep -i open
Max open files            65536                65536       files 

Please let me know if this approach is fine

Comment: Besides that your comment is barel readable: Yes, this exactly the way to go.

You only should track where `pacemaker.service` is coming from --> better create a drop-in.

Comment: @ppuI did type the comment properly but the site posted it like in one row. Sorry about that. 
Just one more question. The problem is, I dont know how many files are being opened by pacemaker when this issue occurs. So does increasing the open file size to 65536 will fix the problem. What if pacemaker opens more files than the actual count of 65536

Thank you once again

Comment: @Zorrom there's also the option to set LimitNOFILE=infinity ...
But there might still be limits depending on your OS and configuration

Comment: Thanks I will check this too